# Angular - Rendering check boxes according to the amount of data recieved

Tags: angular

I have a scenario like this. I have system where a particular user can have multiple roles like "admin" , "user", "outsider" (the amount of different roles in the db can change). The roles are stored in a database and my angular frontend makes a http get request to obtain those roles. My question is, when a user is created, I have to display a check box for each of those different roles so that the user can mark more than one role for himself. And when the form is submitted using http post method, the backend should be able to identify, which roles the user have checked in order to save data. So in summary,

> 1. Display the check boxes according to the number of data in the Roles table in the database.
> 2. When user mark them, post the data to the backend to be saved.

I usually get the form data using `ngModel`. But in here, I can't think of a way to use it, because the amount of Roles in the database may vary.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngFor` to loop through `roles` and render as a list of checkbox.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="role.isSelected" (ngModelChange)="onRoleChange(role)">{{role.name}}
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
onRoleChange(role) {
    // call your API to save here..
    console.log(role);
  }
```

Here is an example at stackblitz I created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkboxlist
Do check output in console as well..

Comment: Thank you so much! It is the 200% solution I was looking for!! :-)

Comment: Sure. Happy to help. :)